# Поиск данных в SQLite3 c переменной (со значением работает)

Tags: python, sqlite3

Сначала программа спрашивает ИНН, который после ввода значения присваивается переменной:

```
def RKO():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('text.sqlite') # Подключение к БД
    q = connection.cursor() # Создание курсора для работы с БД
    poisk_inn = int(input(“Введите инн организации/ИП: ”))
    sql = "SELECT * FROM UL WHERE ИНН=7719465294“
    q.execute(sql)
    res = q.fetchall()
    for el in res:
    print(el)
```

В данном случае все работает, но если сравнение делать с переменной `poisk_inn`, то возникает ошибка:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('text.sqlite') # Подключение к БД
q = connection.cursor() # Создание курсора для работы с БД
poisk_inn = int(input(”Введите инн организации/ИП: “))
sql = ”SELECT * FROM UL WHERE ИНН=poisk_inn"
q.execute(sql)
res = q.fetchall()
for el in res:
print(el)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: poisk_inn
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает из-за отсутствия кавычек: sqlite думает, что `poisk_inn` — столбец, а такого столбца нет.

Я бы рекомендовал сделать вот так:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM UL WHERE ИНН = ?" # '?' заменяется на ваш параметр
q.execute(sql, (111,))
q.execute(sql, ('инн строкой',))
```